# testing apache fuse fabric ( fuse 6.3 ) confused on steps required

Tags: apache-camel

basically new to apache fabric, I've read the docs able to find, but leads to confusion on what is required for the fabric and how to add and configure existing karaf containers.

I'm just confused on what I need to do next, as to not corrupt or break the system. and how to effectively add existing containers to the fabric.

also, do I need to add the activeMQ brokers to the 3 fabric servers to make the fabric work?

I have 3 fabric servers built, 3 nodes for registry, etc...

```
[id]             [version]  [type]  [connected]  [profiles]              
[provision status]
fabric1-server*  1.0        karaf   yes          fabric                  
success
                                             jboss-fuse-full
                                             fabric-ensemble-0001-1
fabric2-server   1.0        karaf   yes          fabric                  
success
                                             fabric-ensemble-0001-2
fabric3-server   1.0        karaf   yes          fabric                  
success
                                             fabric-ensemble-0001-3
```

I've found a doc that says if you use .cfg files in BASE/etc you can simply convert these .cfg to .properties.

thanks so much for your input and help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that apache fuse fabric project will end in 2022.  Since I really wanted to use the fabric for failover purposes, I have decided to not use fuse fabric and going to implement using heartbeat/Pacemaker/Corosync.

thanks everyone!